# In Python 3.x input type if not assign then by default what it will take 'str' why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num =   (input("Enter the number:"))
print num
if (num == 0):
    print ("The number is zero")
elif (num > 0):
        print ("The number is positive")
else:
        print ("The number is negative")
```

Question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\MK
TECK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Farheen Programs\if
elif 3.6.py", line 4, in <module>
    if (num > 0): TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: A traceback is not a question. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Question is in the title, I guess. There's no deeper reason to _why_ `input` doesn't parse to the type you consider 'logical' for a certain input, this function is just not written to do so. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input) of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

By default input will return type `str`:

```
>>> num = input("Enter the number:")
Enter the number:5
>>> type(num)
<class 'str'>
```

you need to typecast it to int:

```
>>> num =   int(input("Enter the number:"))
Enter the number:5
>>> type(num)
<class 'int'>
```